# Difference that the addition of commas make to a sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, difference, commas, exam-questions

How do the following sentences mean differently?

> The candidates who got high marks were pleased.
>
> The candidates, who got high marks, were pleased.

a. Those who got high marks and those who did not were pleased.

b. While the first sentence implies that others who got low marks were not pleased, the second implies that all candidates got good marks.

c. While the first sentence implies that all candidates got good marks, the second implies that others who got low marks were not pleased.

d. the deletion of parenthetic commas affects the meaning of the two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence (without the commas) means that the high scoring candidates were pleased and says nothing directly about non high scoring candidates.

The second sentence (with commas) means that all candidates got high marks and were pleased about it.

a. is false; it says those who scored well and also those that scored poorly were pleased.

b. may be true but is weak; it requires you to assume something not stated in the first sentence about the non high scorers. Maybe there were no low scorers, just medium scorers that were neither pleased nor displeased.

c. is false because it reversed (switched) the meaning of the two sentences with each other.

d. is true; the deletion of commas affects (changes) the meaning between the two sentences.